# Finding the next available position in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensions array of a fixed size of 50 elements. I need to ask the user for some values and insert them into the array. The problem is "How do I make sure I'm not overwriting anything that's in there?"

There will already be some content in the array when I start the program, but I don't know how much. How can I find the next available ID in the array, to insert my content there without overwriting anything that could be already in there?

I tried using array.GetUpperBound and array.GetLength, however they return fixed values no matter how many elements are already in the array.

I **have** to use an array, I can't use lists or anything like that.

What can I do to find out the next "free" position in my array?

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Is this a homework question? We can guide you to a solution, but answering it outright for you (even though there are multiple potential approaches to this) would be doing a disservice to you. In addition, how are you choosing what indices to insert at?

Comment: Will values be present randomly throughout the array?  Additionally, what constitutes a `null` value in the array - 0, `null`, an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using `Array`, all your values will contain a default value.For example if you have an two-dimensional `int` array like this:

```
 var arr = new int[2, 3];
```

`arr[1,2]` will be equal to `0` which is default value for `int`.Anyway you can define an extension method to find available position for a two-dimensional array like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void FindAvailablePosition<T>(this T[,] source, out int x, out int y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < source.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (source[i, j].Equals(default(T)))
                {
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        x = -1;
        y = -1;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
 var arr = new int[2, 3];
 arr[0, 0] = 12;  // for example
 int x, y;
 arr.FindAvailablePosition(out x,out y);

 // now x = 0, y = 1
```